# Is there a way to sort a listview without having to recreate all its elements?

Tags: .net, wpf, listview, sorting, listcollectionview

I have a listView displaying a bunch of graphs.  I can sort this listview using different criteria.  Unfortunately when I perform sort, the operation took more time than expected and I realized that after the sort was triggered all the graphs were being recreated.

My datasource is an observable collection and the view consists of a chart control and a few labels.  I perform the sort on the view by using the view sort description, so the sort should be performed on the view and not on the data source, right?

```
lstView.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
lstView.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(_field, _lstViewDirection));
```

I have been searching around and it seems that the sort triggers a refresh which removes the UI elements from the control and recreates them ... but this seems unnecessary given I am only ordering the positions of the UI elements.

Is there a way to avoid this refresh behaviour and only reorder the UI elements positions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Virtualization so only the elements displayed in the UI are redrawn instead of the entire collection.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfDataVirtualization.aspx

Comment: I tried UI virtualization and even though it makes the aplication a little more responsive it still recreates all items in the collection.  Also I read all the posts I could find on Data virtualization and in the case of sorting, they still use the SortDescription on a view which will re-initialize all my graphs ...  There must be a way to just change the order of the collection without recreating all the elements ... no?